# Position of 'necesssary'

Tags: adjective-position

I have the following sentence:

"Method A makes on average 14 corrections of the schedule **necessary** for one simulated day"

I am wondering if the position of 'necessary' is correct. An alternative would be:

"Method A makes on average 14 corrections **necessary**  of the schedule for one simulated day"

Update: As I could not really understand the given answers (and they did not reply on my questions) I just wanted to ask again if someone could help me. I'd really appreciate it because I am confused at the moment. I want to use 'necessary' not something with 'required'.

What about the suggestion from Charlie (if I understood him correctl):
"Method A makes on average 14 corrections **necessary in the schedule** for one simulated day'"

Comment: Necessary for one simulated day vs. necessary of the schedule... - Let us go by the proximity of noun/ noun phrase to 'necessary'. That may offer better clarity.

Comment: ' ... requires on average 14 corrections (all necessary) ...'?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ram Pillai. What do you mean by proximity of noun? Can I use the first version of my sentence?

Comment: What is your quote trying to say? Is it that by doing Method A, you now need to make 14 corrections (you didn't need to if you used some other method)? Or that you need to make 14 corrections anyway, and Method A lets you do it (whereas if you used a different method, you couldn't make the corrections)? When you know what you want to say, you can then decide how best to phrase it.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence for your answer. Your first interpretation is right. Due to the use of Method A, 14 corrections of a predefines scheudle are necessary to avoid some violations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move necessary, you have to rephrase the sentence. For instance, you could say "necessary *in* the schedule."

The phrase "necessary of" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is the first version okay?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Charlie. So could I write (using your adivce):'Method A makes on average 14 corrections necessary in the schedule for one simulated day'

Comment: @PeterBe There's nothing wrong with it but I would probably say "Method A makes an average of 14 corrections to the schedule for one simulated day necessary". I would do that because 'the schedule for one simulated day' is a noun phrase and, for me, should not be interrupted.

Comment: Thanks a lot BoldBen for your answer and help :-). I really appreciate it